# Externalize value in @WebInitParam with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jgit

I'm using Spring Boot and [GitServlet](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.http.server/src/org/eclipse/jgit/http/server/GitServlet.java) to make a git http server. Code as below

```java
@WebServlet(name = "GitServlet", urlPatterns = {"/git/*"}, loadOnStartup = 1,
        initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name = "base-path", value = "/var/repos"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "export-all", value = "true")
        })
public class GitServlet extends org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.GitServlet {
}
```

I want to put the servlet init parameter `base-path` value (`/var/repos`) to the Spring config file `application.yml` but cannot find a way to do this.
Is it possible  to externalize value in `@WebInitParam`?